# Linux header 4.9.0-11-amd64 is missing in debian

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, headers

I am a software developer and have only a basic understanding about Linux systems. We are in a migration phase from GCP to AWS and found that the Linux headers are missing while installing Cloud endure agent.

On checking found that the version 4.9.0-11-amd64 is missing in debian repository. Is there any way to install the header version 4.9.0-11-amd64 ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE: This issue is resolved by updating the kernal to the next version

Comment: Which debian and kernel version you are running? cat /etc/debian_version and uname -r

Comment: Debian version is 9.13 and Kernal version is 4.9.0-11-amd64

Comment: If you try apt-get update and apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) ?

Answer (score 2):

Debian 9 (stretch)?

from this thread's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543631)

edit (or create) */etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapshot.list*

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190925T034604Z stretch main
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190925T034604Z stretch-updates main
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20191020T221221Z stretch/updates main
```

> note : the **20190925**T034604Z is from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543631) date : sept 25 '19

then:

```
apt -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
apt install linux-headers-4.9.0-11-amd64
```

Or you can just install newer kernel